# Why is the alignment of ordered list messed up by default and how to fix it?

Tags: tables, lists, matrices

I was recently trying to form a table inside an ordered list but, there's a small indent in the list with the table that's driving me crazy.

Below is the code snippet-

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}{
    \item{\begin{enumerate}
         \item{
            \textbf{Quantative}- mpg, displacement, cylinders, horsepower, weight, acceleration, year \\
            \textbf{Qualitative}- names, origin
        }
        \item{
         range(mpg)=[9,46.6], range(cylinders)=[3,8], ....
        }
        \item{
            \begin{tabular}{ |c |c |c |c |c |c |c |c |c |}
            \hline
             & mpg & cyl. & disp. & hp & wt. & accl. & year & origin\\
         \hline\hline
         Mean &  & & & & & & & \\
            \hline
            Std. dev. & & & & & & & &\\
            \hline
         \end{tabular}
    }
    \end{enumerate}
    }}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

As you may see in the image, there's an extra space in the first and the third list. How can I remove it?
[image: zoomed out output]

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).
Note `\item` does not take a parameter, so you should remove parentheses there. "there's an extra space in the third list" should be "there's a vetrical space before the third list item (c)"?

Comment: Please clarify *where* the "small indent" may be visible.

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear (at least to me) what is your problem. Do you like to have vertical aligned item `3`  and first row in table in it (as guessing @dexteritas in his comment)? If not, please provide an sketch of desired result.

Comment: @Zarko Sorry, this was my first question and I didn't explain it clearly. I have extended my code to MWE and included another image to what my problem is

Comment: @Mico Please see the extra image that I have included right now

Comment: @dexteritas I am new to LaTeX so, I didn't know parenthesis weren't necessary, Also, there wasn't really any vertical space before the third(c) list item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "small indent" you've discovered has *nothing* to do with the fact that the third item in the level-2 list is associated with a `tabular` environment. Instead, the indent is caused by the fact that the letters 'a', 'b', 'c' are not all equally wide and are right-aligned. Now, 'c' just happens to be a tad narrower than both 'a' and 'b'. And, if you look *really closely*, you might notice that 'a' is ever so slightly narrower than 'b'. I suppose that if the list carried on to items `(l)` and `(m)` -- the narrowest and widest lowercase letters, respectively -- the right-alignment matter would have become fairly self-evident.

If you simply can't stand this situation, I suggest you (a) load the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package and (b) start the level-2 enumeration with the option `align=left`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item 
    \begin{enumerate}[align=left] % <-- note 'align=left' option
    \item 
      \textbf{Quantative} -- mpg, displacement, cylinders, horsepower, weight, acceleration, year \\
      \textbf{Qualitative} -- names, origin
        
    \item range(mpg)=[9,46.6], range(cylinders)=[3,8], \dots
        
    \item
      \begin{tabular}{ | *{9}{c|} }
      \hline
         & mpg & cyl. & disp. & hp & wt. & accl. & year & origin\\
      \hline
      Mean       & & & & & & & & \\
      \hline
      Std.\ dev. & & & & & & & & \\
      \hline
      \end{tabular}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: There wouldn't by chance be an option to stretch out the letter spacings to be all equal? So, to have letters to be centered within the parenthesis: figuratively ( a ), (b), ( . c . ) ... ( . . l . . ) [hope that renders well].

Comment: @BadAtLaTeXProgramming - Are you pulling my leg?

Comment: @BadAtLaTeXProgramming - If you want to stop drawing some eagle-eyed person's attention to the fact that `(c)` is narrower than `(b)`, etc, just don't surround the lowercase letters with parentheses. Just change `\begin{enumerate}[align=left]` to `\begin{enumerate}[align=left, label=\alph*.]`. That way, only people who bother holding up a micro-ruler to the screen will ever notice that the letters have slightly varying widths...

Comment: I was thinking more of other more verbose labels, but only the idea occured me, no real use case thus far. No idea if ever someone wanted to or would want something like "(one), (two), (three) ...". +1 for the eagle-eyed micro-ruler owners ;D.

Answer (score 4):

#### Description

- I simplified your MWE and added some colored lines with tikz.
- If you look closely, you can see (a) seems also to be not aligned with (b) (red line),
- but if you look on the right side, you can see that the items are right aligned with the green line.
- This is the default and this way also the text is correctly aligned (blue line).

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item
        foo
    \item
        bar
    \item
        foobar
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[red] ([xshift=51.5mm, yshift=-45mm] current page.north west) -- ++(0,-2);
    \draw[green] ([xshift=56.1mm, yshift=-45mm] current page.north west) -- ++(0,-2);
    \draw[blue] ([xshift=58.6mm, yshift=-45mm] current page.north west) -- ++(0,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

- After seeing edited question become more more clear, what bother you.
- This negligible horizontal space before `(c)` hasn't anything with inserted table. Also it is so small (negligible) that it is hard to observe
- Also, its appearing has nothing with inserted table. It will happen at any other item content since it is caused by default align of items labels to the right.
- So, it can be eliminated by aligning items' labels to the left (as show @Mico in his answer).
- So your question title is (still) misleading.

Off-topic:

- even your code fragment is not complete ...
- which list you use in the first level (itemize, enumerate, description?)
- remove all curly brackets around items' contents. As mentioned @dexteritas in his comment, ˙\item` doesn't take a parameters.

On-topic:

- Sorry, but your question (before was edited) was not entirely clear, so you left us to guessing. Bad to me because I try to help you to early)
- Anyway, now I would wrote your code fragment as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}% [align=left] ?
\item   \begin{enumerate}[align=left] 
        \item   \textbf{Quantative}- mpg, displacement, cylinders, horsepower, weight, acceleration, year \\
                \textbf{Qualitative}- names, origin
        \item   range(mpg)=[9,46.6], range(cylinders)=[3,8], ....

        \item   \begin{tblr}[T]{ colspec={|*{9}{c|} }} % <--- observe T
                    \toprule
                            & mpg   & cyl.  & disp. & hp    & wt    & accl. & year & origin \\
                    \midrule
                    Mean    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       \\
                    \midrule[0.1pt, dashed]
                    Std. dev. & & & & & & & &\\
                    \bottomrule
                \end{tblr}
        \end{enumerate}
\item ???
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}

\end{document}
```

However, now arise quation, how should be aligned labels in the first level of list. For example, how should be aligned number 10? Also to left?

[image]

Let me know, if I'm right!

Comment: Could you please see the latest image that I have included. I mean the space is extremely small and I could ignore it but it would be nice to get it resolved. Let me know what you think!

Comment: @SilianRail, your editing was to late (for me) or I answer to early :-). However, difference is so negligible  that it is hard to observe. Now, when is know what bother you I add solution (the same as is in accepted answer).

Comment: I am extremely sorry, I was indeed late.